# SELECT statement issue with php

Tags: linux, php

```
+--------------+------+
| IP           | Say  |
+--------------+------+
| 192.168.1.1  |    1 |
+--------------+------+    

$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db_name") or die("cannot connect");
$Q1 = "SELECT Say From spam_engel WHERE IP = '192.168.1.1'";
$ol = mysqli_query($con, $q1);
echo gettype($ol);
```

Thing printed is "NULL". But it should be printing "int"...
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

php [`variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) are case-sensitive:

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name
>   of the variable. The variable name is **case-sensitive**.

so in your code:

```
$Q1 = "SELECT Say From spam_engel WHERE IP = '192.168.1.1'";
$ol = mysqli_query($con, $q1);
```

here you are using `$Q1` then passing to your `mysql_query()` the lower case variable $q1;

to fix this unify the case of your variable names as follows:

```
$q1 = "SELECT Say From spam_engel WHERE IP = '192.168.1.1'";
$ol = mysqli_query($con, $q1);
```